# How to copy a UITextField with a tap and hold event?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I have several UITextFields setup to move around the screen and are editable with a double tap. I was wondering if there was a way to tap and hold the UITextField to copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try long press gesture on the text field? You can copy the text from it, though I am not sure of the text selection.

The below code is to register textfield with the long press gesture.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];                                                
[textField addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Then callback function when the long press is recognized:

```
-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
     NsLog(@"Text from text field is %@",((UITextField *)[sender view]).text);
}
```

Try this out.

Comment: Any suggestions or tutorials that you know of?

Comment: several error messages....implict decleration of function of NSlog, use of undeclared indentifier 'self'

Comment: Thanks for your help! Know anything about about UIScrollviews zooming with a pinch gesture? Posted question today.

Comment: No problem. I have suggested something for your question. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

set up a UILongPressGestureRecognizer: and see if textFieldShouldBeginEditing: is fired also? if it is, then you can just copy the text field in there.  i have no idea if will fire or if the gesture recognizer would "over ride" it?

Comment: Would it be better to making it a triple tap to copy the textField?